# a:contains(".obj")') to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, contains

I'm trying to check all my links for the word .obj in a certain text.
So far I've bin able to hide that link. But I need to get that link in a variable and output it to the console.
How would I do this right?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Hides all link containing .obj
    $('a:contains(".obj")').hide();

    //Get link in variable (DOES NOT WORK)
    var $objlink = $('a:contains(".obj")');

    //Show variable in console
    console.log($objlink);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="link1" href="#">.obj 1</a>
<a id="link2" href="#">.obj 2</a>
<a id="link3" href="#">.foobar</a>
```

Comment: Your code works for me when I try it. You can try it too, since I edited your question to turn it into an executable snippet. It appears that your problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: well the link in the text is https://www.papercraftplaza.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/stormtrooperhelmetEp7.obj

And this isn't the output I'm getin the console.
When I do alert($objlink); instead of the console log I get this "[object Object]"

Comment: That's hardly a surprise: `alert()` needs a string, it does not know how to display arbitrary objects. And the way your browser's console shows them will depend on which browser you're using, although pretty much all of them should be able to display the contents of a jQuery object in *some* way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of outputting the whole jquery object, go through it and log the `href`.

```
$objlink.each(function(){

   console.log($(this).attr('href'))

})
```